# Uniqueness of the real line

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

A few days ago, I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569826/uniqueness-of-the-real-numbers) in a review queue. I tried my luck at it. Here is what I did:

1. If I want a homomorphism (isomorphism, but even just homomorphism) $f:\mathbb{R}\to F$, then I'll need 0 and 1 to map to themselves. From this, via homomorphism properties, I conclude $\mathbb{Q}$ has to map to itself.
2. $F$ is ordered, so it has an order topology which is easily seen to be Hausdorff. So I can take the identity of $\mathbb{Q}$ and extend it to $f:\mathbb{R}\to F$ via sequential continuity, i.e. if $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\in\mathbb{Q}$, I want $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $F$. This is a well-defined extension.
3. $f$ is order preserving. Naturally, I am assuming "ordered subfield" means the operations and order of $F$ restrict the the normal operations and order of $\mathbb{Q}$. With that, that it preserves the order of $\mathbb{Q}$ is obvious. So let e.g. $a\in\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, which is what allows $f$ to be defined on all $\mathbb{R}$, so there exists $a_n\to a$ a sequence of rationals. Naturally, $f(a)=\lim f(a_n)$. $a_n$ has to eventually be in every open set around $a$, including $(a-\frac d2,a+\frac d2)$, where $d=b-a$. So eventually $a_n<b$, and $f(a_n)<f(b)$ since $b$ is rational. But then $f(a)>f(b)$ is a contradiction. So $f(a)\leq f(b)$. We need injectivity to conclude strict preserving of the order. Oh with similar arguments we conclude for the case $a,b$ both irrational. I'm having problems recalling my proof of this injectivity…
4. $f$ is a homomorphism. On the rationals it is evident, so let $a,b$ be irrational. Then $a_n\to a,b_n\to b$ exist in the rationals. $a_nb_n\to ab$, so $f(ab)=\lim f(a_nb_n)=\lim(f(a_n)f(b_n))=\lim f(a_n)\cdot\lim f(b_n)=f(a)f(b)$. Similarly you prove additive linearity.

So modulo recalling the proof of injectivity, we have proven that any complete ordered field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ as an ordered subfield must contain an isomoprhic copy of $\mathbb{R}$, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ if equipped with the restricted order topology, as one can easily verify since sequential continuity, which is the basis for the definition of $f$, implies continuity in first countable spaces and the order topology is first countable by taking intervals of size $\frac1n$ as local bases. Completeness of $F$ was of course used when defining $f$ via limits, to ensure those limits existed: the sequences of rationals are Cauchy both in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $F$, so the images converge by completeness of $F$.

We are left with proving $f(\mathbb{R})=F$, i.e. $f$ is surjective. I tried by contradiction, and assumed there was $x\in F\smallsetminus f(\mathbb{R})$. I concluded all real multiples of $x$ were of that kind, i.e. not reals, except for $0x=0$. But I can't see how to go on from there.

Can you help me? Is there a more algebraic and less topological way, perhaps an easier way, to do this?

Comment: google complete ordered field, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269353/isomorphism-of-dedekind-complete-ordered-fields and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160249/complete-ordered-field and http://spot.colorado.edu/~baggett/appendix.pdf and http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/eprints/paper_12_27257_140.pdf and and http://www.math.umaine.edu/~farlow/sec52.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, let's say that in an ordered field $F$ and a subfield $K$ of $F$, a sequence $u: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow F$ is $K$-Cauchy if $\forall \varepsilon \in K, \varepsilon > 0 \rightarrow \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n,p \in \mathbb{N}, n,p \geq N \rightarrow |u_n-u_p| < \varepsilon$.

Your theorem (more preceisely part 2 of your proof) holds if completeness is interpreted as the convergence (in the order topology) of every $\mathbb{Q}$-Cauchy sequence of $F$, but not if means convergence of every $F$-Cauchy sequence. Informally, in the latter case, when $F$ is not archimedean - yes, non archimedean ordered fields do exist -, being $F$-Cauchy is much more restricting than being $\mathbb{Q}$-Cauchy because terms of the sequence have to be infinitesimally close to each other.

To end your proof, you could start by proving that $F$ is archimedean, because then its smallest subfield $\mathbb{Q}$ would be dense in it and this would yeild surjectivity. To prove this, assume there is $\omega \in F$ greater than every integer and prove that $(\frac{1}{n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cauchy in $F$ (this is clear) but it doesn't converge in the order topology (here use $\omega$).

You can first prove the more general fact that every convergent sequence in the order topology is $F$-Cauchy.

Comment: The sequence which is not Cauchy in $F$ assuming that $\omega$ is not $F$-Cauchy since no difference of terms of that sequence can be smaller than $\frac1\omega$, and this suggests a reason to assume convergence of $\mathbb Q$-Cauchy sequence instead of $F$-Cauchy ones: some of the former might not be of the latter. OK. Well so that $\omega$ cannot exist. So for any $\omega$ there is a greater integer. This implies archimedeanness since if $a<b$, then find $n>\frac ba$ and we have $na>n\frac ba=b$, which is archimedeanness.

Comment: But how does archimedeanness imply density of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Yes (there is a typo in the very end though).
Well, it is the same thing as proving $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ using the integer part: if $x <y$ are two elements of $F$, you have to find $(p,q) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $x < \frac{p}{q} < y$, shich is the same as finding some natural number $q$ such that $[qx;qy]$ contains an integer. So you just have to chose $q$ big enough so that $q|x-y| >1$. Since $F$ is archimedean, there is such $q$.

Comment: For the record, in class we proved $\mathbb Q$ was dense "by hand": the reals were decimal alignments for us,so given $x\neq y\in\mathbb R$ one takes the first decimal figure which is not the same in $x,y$, chooses the greater value of the two that figure takes in the two numbers, and puts all zeros after it. The number with the lesser value of that figure is thus less that the one constructed, and the other one is greater or equal. If it is equal, one chooses the lesser value and continues with nines till the first non-nine in the lesser number.

Comment: If one wants an irrational, after the figure (or after enough nines) one just continues with $1101001000...$ (i.e. 1, 10, 100, 1000, ...).

Comment: Yes, a formal way of  doing the first thing is defining $y_n = \frac{\left\lfloor10^ny\right\rfloor}{10^n}$ and prove that $y_n$ converges increasingly to $y$, in parcitular there is some $y_n$ in $]x;y[$.

For further study of ordered fields and Cauchy-completeness, you could try and find out about the notion of cofinality (but it requires some set theory)