# Construct a complete and totally ordered ﬁeld that does not have the least upper bound property.

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, order-theory, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I have known about the uniqueness of real line. But I am told that it is possible to construct a field which is order and Cauchy complete without the least upper bound property in absence of the Archimidean property.

So may I ask how can we do that? Considering all the fields which can be ordered, even a fraction field, could someone explicitly give a construction with some explaination? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hyperreal fields come to mind, but they're not metric, so we need uniform completeness I presume?

Comment: Have you tried the surreal numbers to see if they qualify? What about the hyperreal numbers?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160249/complete-ordered-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) seems to give an answer.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Acutally I have not learnt about uniform completeness, the question is just asking about Cauchy completeness.

Comment: @Y.X. Cauchy sequences can be defined in non-metric spaces, as well as Cauchy filters.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot, it seems to be what I am seaching for.But could you please explan how can we order the elements and why it is complete and does not have the least upper bound property? The book did not give a proof.