# Defining metrics as a function to something other than the reals.

Tags: metric-spaces

Generally speaking, a metric for a space R is defined as a function from RxR -> Reals, but does it have to be? Can we define it in more generic terms such as a function from R to a field with certain properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. An ordered field will work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_metric

Comment: Is there much work done on such metric spaces?

Comment: @vasshu I don't know, but I doubt they would be terribly interesting. The only difference between an arbitrary ordered field and $\mathbb R$ is the word "complete", so the only peculiarities one will find in generalized metric spaces would be those of nonconvergent Cauchy sequences.

Comment: There would also be fields in which the Archimedean property doesn't hold.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I was thinking of Dedekind completeness. (Which is Cauchy completeness combined with Archimedean. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121544/least-upper-bound-property-implies-complete )

Comment: No worries. I've been jotting down some ideas, but I haven't found anything too useful yet.

Comment: If you are looking for a generalization of metric space perhaps uniform space might cut it, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space

Comment: @dioid While uniform spaces are interesting, I think they may be more generalized than what I am looking for. Think I should ask a new question about existence of written material on the concept of a generalized metric or would that be too open ended?