# Examples of Cauchy complete ordered fields that are not $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: analysis, examples-counterexamples, big-list, complete-spaces, ordered-fields

According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/121609), it is *not* true that Cauchy completeness (every Cauchy sequence has a limit) and Dedekind completeness (every nonempty set that is bounded above has a supremum) are equivalent for ordered fields. The link in the post is sadly not working (I wish people kept their notes up). The user says,

> Since the Archimedean hypothesis often goes almost without saying in calculus / analysis courses, many otherwise learned people are unaware that there are non-Archimedean sequentially complete fields. In fact there are rather a lot of them, and they can differ quite a lot in their behavior: e.g. some of them are first countable in the induced (order) topology, and some of them are not.

This is actually surprising to me, because I had a contrary false misconception. I think my misconception comes from the mantra that "$\mathbb{R}$ is the unique complete ordered field," which is misleadingly false unless we either refer to Dedekind completeness (which is usually termed as the least upperbound property) or we are presupposing the Archimedean property (which to be honest should be stated explicitly).

So I'm very curious, what are the examples of Cauchy complete ordered fields that are not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? Can we make a list of these fields?

Comment: It's instructive to see why the proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique *Dedekind*-complete ordered field breaks down for *Cauchy*-completeness. Basically, a non-Archimedean ordered field $F$ cannot be Dedekind-complete since (the canonical image in $F$ of) $\mathbb{N}$ can't have a least upper bound (if $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $\mathbb{N}$ then so is $\alpha-1$). But $\mathbb{N}$ is in no way a Cauchy sequence, so this doesn't give any purchase for the Cauchy situation.

Comment: It's also important to get the right notion of "Cauchy sequence." I'm not an expert but I believe that a Cauchy sequence in an ordered field $F$ needs to be a sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for each $\alpha$ in $F_{>0}$ - not $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$! - there is some $n$ such that for all $i,j>n$ we have $\vert a_i-a_j\vert<\alpha$. The fields where all Cauchy sequences are constant, which were mentioned in the linked answer, are the non-first-countable fields - basically, fields where we can't approach $0$ by a sequence.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'd imagine Conway's surreal number system would be a candidate, but it doesn't qualify as a set.

Comment: 3 Examples of Cauchy complete ordered fields that are not Archimedean: (1) the Laurent series field which is an extension of $\mathbb{R}$ as a field extending the order of $\mathbb{R}$. (2) the Levi-Civita field which is an extension of the Laurent series field as a field extending the order of the latter. (3) the Hanh series field which is an extension of the Levi-Civita field as a field extending the order of the Levi-Civita field.

Comment: In $\Bbb{R}((x))$ look at the sign of the first non-zero coefficient to find if $\sum_{n\ge -N} a_n x^n\ge 0$. This makes it an ordered field which is also Cauchy sequence complete for the order topology. It is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ because $x^{-1}$ is larger than every element of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: OK, so just looking at @NoahSchweber's definition here, let's say that we're talking about the sequence $(1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, ...)$. That sequence is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$, because for every positive real $r$, there is some point in the sequence where every pair of successive terms after are closer than $r$. But that very same sequence would *not* be a Cauchy sequence in any non-Archimedean field extension of $\Bbb R$, like the Levi-Cevita field, because now there are positive infinitesimal elements $\epsilon$ which are smaller than the difference of any two successive terms. (1/2)

Comment: As a result, we have that $(1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, ...)$ doesn't converge to anything in any non-Archimedean field extension of $\Bbb R$, but the quirk of the definition is such that this no longer counts as a Cauchy sequence, thus doesn't serve as a counterexample to Cauchy-completeness for these fields. Is that the right idea?